# JavaFX проблемы с TableView на различных объектах

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Есть SplitPane, в которую я вложил TableView. И появляются некоторые вопросы.
1. TableView должна подстраиваться под разные типы объектов (в настоящий момент 3, планирую больше). После переключения на одну из вкладок TreeView генерируется стирается предыдущая и генерируется новая таблица на одном и том же TableView. Это хорошее решение или возможно его как-то улучшить/изменить?
2. Окрашивание строк. Я хочу залить строки цветом лишь той таблицы, которая соответствует только одному из моих объектов. Но "окрашиватель" идёт на каждую таблицу и постоянно генерирует исключение несовместимости объектов. Может, я допускаю ошибку при реализации окрашивателя?

```
tableView.setRowFactory(rows -> new TableRow<MyClass>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(MyClass item, boolean empty) {
                TreeItem<String> nValue = (TreeItem<String>) treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                if (nValue.getValue().equals("String")) {
                    if (item != null) {
                        if (!item.isActive()) {
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkorange; -fx-text-background-color: black;");
                        } else {
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-text-background-color: black;");
                        }
                    }
                }
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
            }
        });
```

3. Всё тот же окрашиватель. По идее, он должен менять цвет строки при нажатии на неё(потому что item.isActive меняет своё значение при нажатии), но такого не происходит. и я немного не понимаю, почему так происходит. Что тут не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. TableView должна подстраиваться под разные типы объектов

Уточните этот момент, не совсем понятно.

**UPDATE.** Судя по комментарию, что у вас разные классы MyClass1, MyClass2 и тд и тп., необходимо

1. Либо выделить из этих сущностей одну общую и ей оперировать ( Например, обозвав SuperMyClass и параметрезировав тогда этим классом объект TableView)
2. Либо для каждого класса создавать отдельную таблицу, которая будет параметризирована своим классом.

> 2. Но "окрашиватель" идёт на каждую таблицу и постоянно генерирует исключение несовместимости объектов

Приведите код, потому что тоже не совсем понятно

> 3. но такого не происходит. и я немного не понимаю,

Вся суть в том, что в методе `updateItem(MyClass item, boolean empty)` вам сначала необходимо вызвать `super.updateItem(item, empty)`, а уже потом писать свою логику.

Comment: 1. У меня есть объекты MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3. У каждого различные поля, которые не пересекаются. И под каждый объект я таблицу сначала чищу, а потом привязываю по новой новый объект.  
2. Вытекает из первого, по сути. Мне нужно чтобы строки красились только когда я задействую объект MyClass1, а этот код исполняется даже когда текущая таблица построена под MyClass2.  
3. Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: @Lejko7 см апдейт